# How to puts fonts to React Native Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, react-native, fonts

I have React Native project and i need to put custom fonts to Xcode. When i put it there i check mark Copy items if needed, Create groups and in front of the name of my project. And after when i delete the local folder from where i put fonts and i'm getting error from Xcode about can not find fonts from the local storage. Can you tell me please how can i put fonts that they will be available everywhere and the will not depend from the local storage?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the web font you want to use to your project in a folder called `Fonts`

1. Now in `Xcode`, in the Project folder, "Add Files to Project
   Name...Click on ""
2. Navigate to the parent folder and add the Fonts folder you just
   added.
3. Check and add '`Create folder references`' and '`Add to targets`' in the
   process of adding.
4. Click `Info.plist`, add '`Fonts provisioned by application` array'
   with '`Add Row`' and add as many `items` as the `font` count.
5. It kills an app that used to work and rebuilds and executes it.
   (command + shift + K => command + shift + B => command + shift + R)

**Usage**

```js
 font1 : {
        fontFamily: "NanumSquareR"
    },
```